# How can I benchmark refreshing of matplotlib window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, benchmarking

My matplotlib plots are quite heavy (it takes several minutes to refresh window after resizing it). It is especially annoying as the IPython shell freezes till the window is refreshed.

I would like to optimize them for speed, however I have no idea how may I benchmark the refresh time?

I tried to use IPython's magic command `%time` - unfortunately the only thing which is being measured is the execution time of the routine, and not the window refresh time.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? How do you resize the window?

Comment: By dragging its boundary or by maximizing/unmaximizing it.

Comment: matplotlib has a `draw_event` and a `resize_event`. But I don't know at which point in time they will be triggered compared to the actual events.